# Bootstrap x-editable, PDO UPDATE issue

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

been stuck on this one. I'm using x-editable from jquery, I am calling my data  through a php loop. Here is What i've got, my headers throw no error, just don't know where I'm going wrong? is there something I am missing or doing wrong? Everything works fine it just won't update the record in mysql?

Heres my loop:

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM retailers ORDER BY id ');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
echo "<tr>
<td>
<a href='#' data-type='text' data-pk='{$row['id']}' data-placement='right' class='store'  data-url='actions/post.php' data-title='Store Name:' data-name='store'  value='{$row['store']}'>{$row['store']}</a>
</td>
</tr>"; } ?>
```

Here my PDO update:

```
$store = $_POST['store'];
$id = $_POST['id'];

$sql = "UPDATE retailers SET store=?
        WHERE id=?";
$q = $db->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($store,$id));
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

(Calling x-editable)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$('.store').editable();

});
```

Comment: Have you set PDO into exception error mode, ie `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION)`? Your level of error reporting may be hiding a statement error

Comment: Also, PHP alt syntax is much easier for creating markup with PHP values interjected - http://pastebin.com/S3cgcKS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [X-editable examples](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html), it seems you will want to use

```
$id = $_POST['pk'];
```

Also, as mentioned in my comment above, using [PHP's alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) makes for much easier markup creation. Also, `value` is an invalid attribute here. If you must use it, I think X-editable uses `data-value` but it can also read from the element's HTML contents.

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM retailers ORDER BY id ');
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) : ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="#" data-type="text" data-pk="<?= $row['id'] ?>"
           data-placement="right" class="store" data-url="actions/post.php"
           data-title="Store Name:" data-name="store"><?= htmlspecialchars($row['store']) ?></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Comment: Thank you, I end up working around your script and got it working! you showed me a brand new approach to loop too! I am very thankful you took your time here to review my question and give me a solution! I don't mean to trouble you again, I looking for some advice now on updating multiple records, here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19252959/update-multiple-records-according-to-id-x-editable any more advice would be soo appreciated! Kindest Regards friend!